# What type to use to correctly handle division of odd numbers of cents? (or smallest units of any currency)

Tags: go, rounding, currency

Most of the time I see recommendations to represent money as its most fundamental unit; and to use 64 bit unsigned integer to provide maximal capacity.

On the surface this seems fine, but what about the case where I want to split 1 cent?

In Java/Scala the BigDecimal type, which I also see recommended for handling money, will track fractions of a cent, 0.01/2 = 0.005

But dividing a 64 bit unsigned int, 1/2 = 0

I'm trying to write some Go that handles money, and want to know which type to use (just use uint64 or find something else?).

Thank you!

Comment: @user2864740 I want to know what type to use, isn't that on-topic?

Comment: If you're splitting `X` amount of money (e.g. indivisible integer cents) between three places with `X/3` then you're doing it wrong. With money you'd need to do something like `a, b := X/3, X/3; c := X-a-b` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`big.Rat`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) for rational numbers of arbitrary size. Then you can split quantities to your heart's content without losing any precision.

Comment: I was reading about doing that, just found this google groups comment though https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/q-vQS9cb9uI/sojYMFeXoI0J

Thoughts? I think I'll probably go with big.Rat for now. Optimize later :) The package mentioned there http://godoc.org/speter.net/go/exp/math/dec/inf is currently experimental

Comment: True, but your are free to manually limit the precision, depending on your specific needs. To me the biggest drawback is that you have to use methods instead of operators which makes the code more verbose and thus a little bit harder to read.

Comment: User-defined arithmetic operators would be more than just nice in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

`int64` (or `uint64`) still can be used to represent monetary amounts with cent fractions. E.g. if the minimum amount that you want to operate with is `0.01` cents then you can represent `1` cent as `100`, then half a cent will be `50` and `1/100` of a cent will be `1`. This representation is very efficient (from performance and memory usage point of view) but not very flexible. Things to be aware of are:

- there is maximum value (`~2^64/100` cents) that you can represent using this method
- changes will be required to the app and its stored data if the maximum precision changes
- all arithmetic operations needs to be carefully implemented taking rounding into account

Comment: It looks as though `bigFloat` is *binary* floating-point arithmetic, though, so it wouldn't be as well-suited to monetary calculations as a decimal floating-point (or fixed-point) type.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, you are right. I will remove it from my answer.

Comment: Fixed point arithmetic via a user-defined type based on int64 and a quotient might be a good way to achieve clearly understandable code, with the necessary precision and good performance. It sounds too much like rolling your own BigDecimal, though.